# C# Console App - Run a Process as Local Admin and Network User (Windows)

Tags: c#, windows, console-application, process.start, network-shares

I'm trying to figure out a way of running Process.Start with 2 lots of credentials if at all possible?

I need to run cscript.exe with a load of arguments from Process.Start within a C# console app that A, needs to be run as the Local Administrator and B, needs access to a network share to pull a wsf script file for cscript to work with.

Process.Start seems to only accept one lot of credentials so I can only satisfy one or the other conditions...

Any ideas how I could possibly execute the process as the local admin but also wrap the entire thing in a network access session using credentials?

Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't it copy the `wsf` somewhere locally using one set of credentials and then execute using the local copy using the other set? Why does it have to be one process that does both of these things?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's a good idea actually, didn't think of that :) I was just wondering if it could be done using some sort of combination of impersonation and executing as local admin...